# Publishing Marker arrow causes Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: ros, marker, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to publish a marker arrow and want to visualize it in rviz with a start and an end point.

When I am using the points member as described here http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Arrow_.28ARROW.3D0.29 and try to run it I am getting the following error: Segmentation fault (core dumped).

When I am just using the pose.position and pose.orientatien without the points member the arrow is appearing.

```
    visualization_msgs::Marker markers_msg;
    markers_msg.header.frame_id = "world";
    markers_msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    markers_msg.ns = "drop";
    markers_msg.id = 0;
    markers_msg.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::ARROW;
    markers_msg.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
    markers_msg.pose.position.x = 1;
    markers_msg.pose.position.y = 1;
    markers_msg.pose.position.z = 1;
    markers_msg.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
    markers_msg.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
    markers_msg.pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
    markers_msg.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
    markers_msg.lifetime = ros::Duration(0);
    markers_msg.scale.x = 1;
    markers_msg.scale.y = 0.1;
    markers_msg.scale.z = 0.1;
    markers_msg.color.a = 1.0; // Don't forget to set the alpha!
    markers_msg.color.r = 1.0;
    markers_msg.color.g = 0.0;
    markers_msg.color.b = 0.0;
    markers_msg.points[0].x = 0.0f;
    markers_msg.points[0].y = 0.0f;
    markers_msg.points[0].z = 0.0f;
    markers_msg.points[1].x = 1.0f;
    markers_msg.points[1].y = 1.0f;
    markers_msg.points[1].z = 1.0f;
```

I hope anyone can help me. Thank you very much in advance!

Kind regards,

Raphael

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378596/publishing-marker-arrow-causes-segmentation-fault-(core-dumped)/) by [RaphaelHoefer](https://answers.ros.org/users/74816/raphaelhoefer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks more like a C++ issue:

```
visualization_msgs::Marker markers_msg;
...
markers_msg.points[0].x = 0.0f;
markers_msg.points[0].y = 0.0f;
markers_msg.points[0].z = 0.0f;
markers_msg.points[1].x = 1.0f;
markers_msg.points[1].y = 1.0f;
markers_msg.points[1].z = 1.0f;
```

`marker_msgs.points` is a `std::vector`. You don't seem to `resize(..)` or `reserve(..)` any elements, so `markers_msg.points[1]` almost certainly indexes into uninitialised memory.

The `[]` operator [does not perform any bounds checking](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator%5B%5D/), so you don't get any errors, but it does cause *undefined behaviour*.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RaphaelHoefer](https://answers.ros.org/users/74816/raphaelhoefer/) on 2021-05-19**:
Thank you very much! This solved the problem.